# Sci-fi space movie, with destroyed Earth (appeared purple-ish with alien-like features)

Tags: identify-this-movie, science-fiction

I'm trying to figure out the name of a certain sci-fi space movie. I can vaguely remember the plot and I've recently (?) watched it too.

The Earth was supposedly ravaged by a war, then turned into a peace haven by some Space Union where no one was allowed to return. Only to be discovered by the main characters that the Earth was actually in fact completely destroyed, the Earth appeared purple-ish in color and had weird alien like features.

But at the end, a small glimmer of life on Earth was found (I remember a small plant) and that's pretty much what I  remember.

Comment: Was it animated? Sounds a lot like the plot of Wall-E.

Comment: The plant sounds like Wall*E but there was no war nor peace haven plot line in that film.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like it could be [Space Pirate Captain Harlock](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2668134/)

> In the future, mankind has discovered a way to travel faster than light and has built colonies on thousands of planets. With humanity fading and the resources of the universe starting to dwindle, some five hundred billion humans began the long journey back home, to Earth. However, humanity has outgrown its capacity to repatriate that many people and thus began the "Homecoming War;" where the many factions of humanity battled for a stake on Earth. The war was long and bloody. It did not subside until an authoritarian universal government by the name of the **Gaia Sanction declares Earth a sacred planet**, and thus forbidden for humanity to repopulate.

....

> **The dark matter was uncontrollable and it decimated the Earth and life was no longer sustainable**.

....

> At Harlock's cell, Yama reveals what he had found on Earth. **The flower meant that Earth is trying to recover on its own** and it might be the "starting over" that Harlock wanted. Emotionally touched at the significance of this miraculous find, Harlock believes he's found his "freedom". Harlock intends to expose the truth of Earth and escapes with the Arcadia.

Here is an image of the purple Earth:
[image: Purple Earth]

Comment: I think so too. Maybe I was so busy trying to search for a Hollywood movie that I didn't even consider an animated movie... I'll have a look into it later.

Comment: You might want to elaborate in which way this movie fits to the description from the question in order to flesh out the answer a little more.

Comment: Who down voted this answer? o.o Anyways, thanks for the answer DFreeman!

Comment: @Shuya *"Who down voted this answer?"* - The same person who explained in a constructive comment what's wrong with it and how to improve it. Why? Is it relevant who downvoted it? It seems enough that you know how the answer can be improved into non-downvotability.